# Programmatically impersonating another user without causing the currently logged-in user to log out

Tags: 7, users

How should a module change the value of the global `$user`, execute its own code, and restore the original value of `$user` without causing the current user to be logged out if an error happens?

Comment: There is an old issue open about this, which adds a function that can properly handle this, even when called multiple times. See http://drupal.org/node/287292.

Please review and test the patch there.

Comment: There has been a Community Documentation create that has the solution to impersonate another user for Drupal 6, Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 on drupal.org: [Safely Impersonating Another User](https://www.drupal.org/node/218104).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [drupal_cron_run()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7) function gives a perfect example for exactly this, since it changes the current user to anonymous whenever cron is run, then switches back after it is done.

```
// Prevent session information from being saved while doing funky stuff.
$original_session_state = drupal_save_session();
drupal_save_session(FALSE);

// Force the current user to anonymous to ensure consistent permissions on
// funky stuff runs.
$original_user = $GLOBALS['user'];
$GLOBALS['user'] = drupal_anonymous_user(); // Or use user_load() for a non-anonymous user.

// Do funky stuff here...

// Restore the user.
$GLOBALS['user'] = $original_user;
drupal_save_session($original_session_state);
```

Comment: Worth noting you can put the current user object away somewhere (in `$GLOBALS` or just in another variable for safe-keeping) and switch to *any* user by loading them in with `user_load()`. Which allows you to do some horrible things like masquerade as a specific users set up with specific permissions to perform a specific process. The principle is the same.

Comment: Only potential 1 problem with this piece of code.   You should save the old session in a variable $old_session.  Set the save session to false, then at the end drupal_save_session($old_session).

Comment: Just a note for Drupal 8/9 You can use the [`AccountSwitcher`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountSwitcherInterface.php/function/AccountSwitcherInterface%3A%3AswitchTo/8.9.x) service