# How does the global variable $user work?

Tags: 7, users

Here is my scenario:

I create a new user and dynamically create for him some content on which he is the owner.

Each user can log in, see his content and edit his profile. I use a block in which I have a menu links to each content and to his profile.

The theme output of the block function uses `global $user;` to get the current logged user.

However, the strange thing is that `$user->uid` return the last created user in the system and not the current logged user. Also the `$user->language` is of the last created user in the system. Why?

The user logs out with `user/logout`; this is the command to log out, right? Do I need to do more after user logout such as GLOBAL variable resets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check to see that the block is not getting cached, or that you are not using something like Boost (static caching).

Sounds like the block contents are being cached to me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is true, I have checked and `Cache blocks` was enabled. So this mean that I can not use this function in my case.

Comment: It just means that you need to set the correct cache information for your block in hook_block_info, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7. You probably want to use DRUPAL_NO_CACHE since a per user cache is often undesired (because a *lot* of cache entries are generated). Note that while in D7 this should automatically be updated when you change the code, it does not yet in D6: http://drupal.org/node/235673

Answer (score 3):

`global $user` should ALWAYS refer to the currently logged in user.

There is a good chance that you are probably resetting the global `$user` variable in your custom code. A good practice when dealing with user accounts is to use the `$account` variable to distinguish between the two, see [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/user_save) for an example.

Comment: There are cases where you must *temporarily* replace the global $user object. For example, when trying to use filter_access() in D6 for a different than the currently logged in user since there is no argument to specify account you want to use. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/315/impersonating-the-anonymous-user for how to do that. Anyway, it looks like the issue in this case are simply wrong/missing block cache settings.